# How do I make a website not count my own hits?

Tags: django, hitcounter

I have a website programmed in Django, and as part of the website, I have a view counter for individual pages. However, since I test-view my own files rather often, I don't want to count views that I give to my own pages.

Right now, all I do is that when a specific page is requested, it simply updates a "views" variable in the model for that page by increasing it by 1. This is okay for my own purposes - I don't mind recording multiple views by the same person - but I simply don't want my own views to count.

What ways are there to do this? Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a temporary cookie variable in your browser.

For example, in Chrome, you can use the following or the `Resources` tab on the Web Inspector:

1. browse to website
2. In browser URL bar, type: `javascript:document.cookie="my_app_who_am_i=itsa_me_mario"`

and pull it back using some django:

```
request.COOKIES.get('my_app_who_am_i')
```

Or if you had sessions setup already on your web server, you could set the cookie only when your account logs in.

```
response = render_to_response(template_name, context)
response.set_cookie('my_app_who_am_i', 'itsa_me_mario') 
return response
```

Comment: How would I do this just for myself?

Comment: You would set the cookie locally in your browser, without code, ie: manually.

Comment: Okay, I found a tool to do it. Also, I don't have sessions set up currently, but when I do, I'll use that method instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use session for it. And when the session is for example, admin(you) then, don't count it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a cookie like "ignore_view" and if the cookie is present you don't increase the counter.